# Inno Setup - do command with cmd.exe without launching a batch file

Tags: cmd, inno-setup

I'm trying to use cmd.exe to get Userdomain and Username from %userdomain% and %username% parameters, and put this in a text file to be able to get back the datas.

it works well when I manually launch a command windows and type:
echo %userdomain%\%username% > "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\is-B7P3P.tmp\domainstring_results.txt"

It works well too if a put it in a batch file and launch the .bat

But if I do the same with the Exec function, it only launches cmd.exe and do nothing else :

```
CommandLine := 'echo %userdomain%\%username% > "' + ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\domainstring_results.txt"';
Exec('cmd.exe', CommandLine, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

I don't want to use a batch file because I want to use temporary folder of the installer, so I can't create the batch before the installer compilation.
Cannot be in [Run] section too because I need this information before the Install step...

Comment: I'm not quite sure but don't you need a "/C" preceding the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can get data calling `ExpandConstant('{%WindowsContantNameHere}')`
That should allow you to use necessary data for your purposes.

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  MsgBox('User Name is: ' + ExpandConstant('{%Username}') + #13#10 + 
   'User Domain is: ' + ExpandConstant('{%Userdomain}'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks: ExpandConstant('{%Userdomain}\{%Username}'); does what I was expecting...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`GetUserNameString`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getusernamestring) and [`GetEnv`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getenv) functions:

```pascal
GetUserNameString()
```

```pascal
GetEnv('USERDOMAIN')
```

---

To answer your question: You are missing the `/C` switch. And you should use the [`{cmd}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cmd) instead of hardcoding the `cmd.exe`.

```pascal
Exec(
  ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C ' + CommandLine,
  '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

Though your approach is an overkill.

Comment: So right, this approach is not good at all. But I didn't know about the possibility of passing windowsconstant in ExpandConstant(). So ExpandConstant('{%Userdomain}\{%Username}'); is what I was looking for.

Comment: This would be more lightweight solution: `GetEnv('USERDOMAIN') + '\' + GetUserNameString()`